# Why can we substitute matrix and eigenvalues into other than the characteristic polynomial (Cayley Hamilton)

Tags: linear-algebra, cayley-hamilton

Generally speaking, this is a question about when we can swap $A \rightarrow\lambda$.

In problem 2-5(c) of Applied Optimal Estimation, we are asked to consider the matrix
$$A = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{matrix}\right],$$ whose characteristic polynomial is $$p(\lambda) = \lambda^2-5\lambda-2.$$  We then Taylor expand $e^{At}$ and use Cayley-Hamilton to simplify, yielding: $$e^{At} = a_1(t)I + a_2(t)A.$$

Part (c) of the question is getting a closed form expression for $a_1(t)$ and $a_2(t)$.  To do that, [this solution pdf](https://www.waxworksmath.com/Authors/G_M/Gelb/WriteUp/Weatherwax_Gelb_Solutions.pdf) swaps out $\lambda_1$ and then $\lambda_2$ for $A$, which gives two equations for the two unknowns.

Why can one swap out $\lambda_i$ for $A$ in that expression, if it is not the characteristic polynomial?  Does this hold in general, that while we can't necessarily swap $A$ for $\lambda$, we can always do the reverse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obtained that expression using only the fact that $A$ is a "zero" of the characteristic polynomial. Similarly $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ are zeros of the characteristic polynomial.

If you are still not convinced, just expand $e^{\lambda_1 t}$ and use what you know about $\lambda_1$ to simplify in exactly the same manner as you did with $A$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  They aren't using some property I don't understand about Cayley-Hamilton or polynomial division, it's just that (obviously) you can use the CP to substitute expressions for $\lambda$, just as we can use it for $A$.